# .PolTypeLOB' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Have tried to debug

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to debug this for hours. Any help or tips will be appreciated

```
SELECT PA.PolExec, SUM(ISNULL(PR.Revenue,0) + ISNULL(PF.Revenue,0)) AS Revenue, 
            CASE P.PolTypeLOB
                WHEN 'Me%' THEN 'MED'
                WHEN 'Pres' THEN 'MED'
                ELSE CASE P.TypeOfBus
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'PL'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'CL'
                    ELSE 'BEN'
                END
            END AS PolType
GROUP BY PA.PolExec
ORDER BY PA.PolExec
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX if PolTypeLOB is always the same for all PolExec

```
SELECT PA.PolExec, SUM(ISNULL(PR.Revenue,0) + ISNULL(PF.Revenue,0)) AS Revenue, 
            MAX(CASE P.PolTypeLOB
                WHEN 'Me%' THEN 'MED'
                WHEN 'Pres' THEN 'MED'
                ELSE CASE P.TypeOfBus
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'PL'
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'CL'
                    ELSE 'BEN'
                END
            END) AS PolType
GROUP BY PA.PolExec
ORDER BY PA.PolExec
```

as the error me3ssage says , all columns in a SELECT have3 to be in the GROUP BY or have a [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)